# Express.js + mongodb Using 'ref' to make a connection between collections not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ref

I have searched for this issue for quite a while ( a few days now) but could not find the solution.
SO i have two routes mainly
**http://localhost:3002/api/users** and **http://localhost:3002/api/blogs**

When i add a blog to the blogs endpoint it also includes the user information that created it.

```
 {
    title: "test",
    author: "test",
    url: "localhost.com",
    likes: 5,
    user: {
       username: "Test",
       name: "test1",
       id: "60995c878dbc8f1df4b8bc59"
    },
 id: "609b80225c0d7410081e703b"
},
```

now this works as intened, the scheme that helped me achieve this is:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);

const blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  author: { type: String, required: true },
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  url: { type: String, required: true },
  likes: Number,
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
});

blogSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

blogSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString();
    delete returnedObject._id;
    delete returnedObject.__v;
  },
});

const Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', blogSchema);

module.exports = Blog;
```

Now what i also want to do, for the users endpoint to be able to display the blogs array each user has created and i am using the following scheme for this:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  name: String,
  passwordHash: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  blogs: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Blog'
    }
  ]
});

userSchema.set('toJSON', {
  transform: (document, returnedObject) => {
    returnedObject.id = returnedObject._id.toString();
    delete returnedObject._id;
    delete returnedObject.__v;
    delete returnedObject.passwordHash;
  },
});

userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

But unfortunately, this is what i get at **http://localhost:3002/api/users** :

> 

```
 [
>     {
>      blogs: [ ],
>      username: "Welp",
>      name: "help",
>      id: "60995c878dbc8f1df4b8bc59"
>     },
>     {
>      blogs: [ ],
>      username: "kek",
>      name: "bur",
>      id: "609ba0d9574a412d049deab7"
>     },
>     {
>      blogs: [ ],
>      username: "lallaa",
>      name: "afafafa",
>      id: "609bd08b1f5b52052830459d"
>     } ]
```

Here is my users.js where i get the info

```
> const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const usersRouter = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/user');

//Search for all the users in the database
usersRouter.get('/', async (request, response) => {
  const users = await User.find({}).populate('blog', {title: 1, author: 1, likes: 1});
  response.json(users);
});

//Create a new user with a an encrypted password to the database
usersRouter.post('/', async (request, response) => {
  const body = request.body;


  if (!body.password) {
    return response.status(404).json({error: 'Password not inputed'});
  }

  const saltRounds = 10;
  const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(body.password, saltRounds);

  const user = new User({
    username: body.username,
    name: body.name,
    passwordHash
  });

  const savedUser = await user.save();
  response.json(savedUser);
});

module.exports = usersRouter;
```

I do not understand why the blogs array is still empty, why the blog is populated with users but the user doesnt receive the blogs? I have been trying but cant figure it out. please help :(

Comment: can you share your query about what is used to fetch users data

Comment: I have edited to post and appended the users.js to the end of the post, please check

Comment: It has been a week and i am still stuck on this issue and i can not advance to next step until i find a solution to this... Please anyone

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing to save blogs data in your user's documents. Thats's why when you are fetching users data, you are getting empty blogs array.

You are only saving username, name, passwordHash and forget to save blogs data. Follow the below code, just add the blogs property in the user object.

```
const user = new User({
username: body.username,
name: body.name,
passwordHash,
blogs: body.blogs
});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the issue here, i am trying to create join quaries with mongodb. Where already existing blogs are listed on the users endpoint in blogs array. The opposite works for blogs displaying the user who created them, but user won't show the blogs created by them.
So i am first using ref attribute to connect these two collections and then .populate method to extract specific parts of the collections

Comment: I don't have a misconception. 

You should read the docs properly.  https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html